# Drawable position inside the edittext

Tags: android

I have an image in sdcard, which i want to use it as Drawable in multiline editText. For now, i'm succeeded to display it.

```
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path), 120, 120, false);
final Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
draw.setBounds(0,0,draw.getIntrinsicWidth(),draw.getIntrinsicHeight());
complaintText.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
complaintText.setCompoundDrawables(null,draw,null,null);
```

But i'm want to display at top left position of the multiline edittext.
I'll be grateful for any help

Comment: where it is coming now can you tell me..

Comment: It's at middle top position. I've tried this to
complaintText.setCompoundDrawables(draw,null,null,null);
And it's middle left

Comment: I dont know exactly but have you tried without padding or setting gravity at top-left

Comment: yep tried without padding or gravity still same.

Comment: Have you got any solution